# Write Default Text on Native-Base Input

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, frontend, native-base

I am calling a component like this by passing a string to it:

```
  <TripsPage
          startingPoint={startingPoint}
        />
```

Now in this component, I have this label:

```
<Item fixedLabel>
              <Input/>
            </Item>
```

on the front-end, when we open this screen it is obviously empty. But I want the `startingPoint`string to appear on it as a default input value. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TextInput`. It has property named value through which you can give default text. It has few event like `onChangeText`, It will give us event when ever textInput value change. for more detail please check https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput

```js
<TextInput
      style={{ height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1 }}
      onChangeText={text => onChangeText(text)}
      value={props.startingpoint}
    />
```

Comment: But that comes in the background, like a label. I want it to appear as text. Like when we type something into the field..

Comment: So someone can append text after that. You want that?

Comment: Yes as in, the input field should already be filled with some text. If the user wants, we can change/add/delete that.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25977656)